# Including LaTeX font in PowerPoint chart

Tags: fonts, computer-modern, powerpoint

I am running Windows 7 and create some charts in PowerPoint 2010. I export the charts to PDFs and load them into a LaTeX document.

Can I load the default LaTeX font into Office? How?

Essentially, I just need a few letters in the LaTeX font, but in arbitrary positions in my charts.

Comment: Why don't you use Beamer rather than Powerpoint?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

(**cut-n-paste from my answer to a [similar question](https://superuser.com/q/42420/1711) from Super User**)

That default TeX font is called [Computer Modern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Modern), which might help you in your search. And in the wikipedia link I find

- [Computer Modern typeface in TrueType format](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/ttf/) and [OpenType](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/otf/).
- [Computer Modern Unicode fonts](http://cm-unicode.sourceforge.net/) X11 licensed

and others which are probably just what you need.

Comment: Funny that the truetype/opentype fonts are in a ps-type1 subdirectory...

Answer (score 7):

They are available for download: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/lm/fonts/opentype/public/lm/

Look for `lmroman10-regular.otf` and other sizes/shapes.

How to install them is off topic here (and I wouldn't be able to anser this question anyway :-))

Comment: Thanks. Seems that Powerpoint cannot embed .odf into a PDF... With the .ttf suggested by dmckee it is possible

Comment: I didn't know that Powerpoint can't embed the OpenType fonts into PDF.

Comment: It's an Office-wide problem for versions before 2010: see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908475/en-us - then you could embed OTF fonts if they have Truetype outlines; convincing Office to realise these outlines are there may require changing the filename extension from .otf to .ttf.  I think Office 2010 fixes this issue: there's supposed to be support for generating the missing font information, but I haven't looked at Office 2010 yet.

Comment: As reference: The standard fonts are cmr10 (regular) and cmb10 (bold).

Answer (score 5):

[IguanaTeX](http://www.jonathanleroux.org/software/iguanatex/) is "A Free LaTex Add-In for PowerPoint" similar to [TeX4ppt](http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/srg/softwaretools/presentation/TeX4PPT/) (or [TeX4ppt with enhancements](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~mehtane/latex/index.html)) or [TeXpoint](http://texpoint.necula.org/).

Comment: All the links seem to be dead.

Comment: @gr4nt3d I could find new working links for `IguanaTeX` and `TeXpoint` but not for `TeX4ppt`.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't anyone use TeXPoint anymore? I love it.
http://texpoint.necula.org

Comment: I'd guess it might be the license fee, a philosophical objection to closed-source software, or outright loathing towards MS Office. Personally -- all of them.

Comment: @Martin - I bow to no one in my loathing of MS Office. But, I am forced to use it now and then in my work, so I use TeXpoint for the math. Also, I got it when the company was giving it away for free, and, last time I tried it, it still worked with the version of Powerpoint that I was using (not the latest).

Comment: I'm slightly partial to MathType for mathematics in MS Office. I'm guilty of purchasing a license in my dark pre-TeX days. It accepts input in (La)TeX math mode, so it's pretty easy to quickly typeset a hairy tensor-equation-with-integrals-and-funny-symbols, saving one from the excruciatingly painful clickfest that is Microsoft Editor. Useful mostly in Word, as the equations in PP are like graphical objects and are not aligned with the text in any way.